# An equivalent condition for the localization map $M\to M_P$ to be injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

How do I show that given a prime ideal $P\subset R$, the map of $M\to M_P, m\mapsto m/1$ is injective if and only if $R\setminus P$ contains no elements killing a nonzero element of $M$?

One direction looks easy. Suppose the map is not injective. Then $m/1=m
'/1$ for some $m\ne m'$. So there is $v\in R\setminus P$ with $v(m-m')=0$ in $M$. So $v$ kills the nonzero element $m-m'$ of $M$.

The other direction isn't that easy. Suppose $v\in R\setminus P$ kills an element $m\ne 0$. How to prove that the map isn't injective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because $\dfrac m1=0$ in $M_P$ by definition since $vm=0$ in $M$, hence  the kernel of the canonical map (which is $R$-linear) is not reduced to $0$.

Comment: I was trying to find two elements that map to the same one, but apparently I shouldn't have gone that far.

Comment: Yes, linearity simplifies, as always…